# Let $\hat{g}=f.$ Is $g$ continuous?

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, transformation, fourier-transform

Let $f: \mathbb R \to  \mathbb C$ such that there exists $g\in L^{1}(\mathbb R)$ with $\hat{g}=f.$ Then by Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma, we have  $f$ is continuous  and vanishing at infinity.

> My Question is: Can we say $g$ is also continuous on $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Do you know an example of a discontinuous function in $L^1$?  What happens when you take its Fourier transform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, we can't say that $g$ is continuous.

For example, take $g(x)=0$ for every $x \neq 0$ and $g(0)=1$. Then $g \in L^1$, $f=\hat{g}=0$, but $g$ is not continuous.

Another, less trivial, example is given by $g=\chi_{[0,1]}$. Indeed we have $f(\xi)=\hat{g}(\xi)=\frac{1 - e^{-2\pi i \xi}}{2\pi i\xi}$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/115929/258310) for a computation) which is continuous (more precisely, can be extended continuously through the origin) but $g$ is not.